# I can't see my other projects in Eclipse!

Tags: eclipse

I've been using Eclipse with each project in a separate window by right clicking on a project and selecting Open in New Window. This worked fine, but suddenly... even when I close Eclipse and reopen it, the Navigator only shows one of the projects I was working on. How can I navigate back???

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also, in the package explorer, click on the arrow on the top right corner of that explorer, and select 'Top Level Elements/***Working sets***' (instead of 'Top Level Elements/Projects'.

That way, you get back a working set (set of projects) view, allowing you to reopen any project of your choice in a new window.

When it comes to PDT (PHP development environment), you should have useful options ion that same arrow at the top right cornet of the PHP explorer:

[image]

(and [selecting the right files](http://www.102degrees.com/blog/2007/07/11/show-the-right-files-in-php-explorer/) can be confusing too!)

Comment: I'm not sure this does what I need it to, at least using the PHP Explorer (which does have that same menu that you mention). Once I'll figure this out I'll mark yours as best answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't work for me for PHP projects, not even using the Package Explorer itself (instead of the PHP Explorer... they end up showing the same thing). Thanks for the answer... I'll investigate more.

Comment: I just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268892 ;)
Duh! Community wiki question though. I have not yet mastered this 'point' game... :)

Comment: I get it now! If you are looking at ONLY a single project you can't see the workspace, so you have to do Window-->New Window first... Thanks!

Comment: @Glo "Broken Image Repairer"... it does work well! Again, thank you for the edit.

Comment: You're welcome! I expect it'll repair over a thousand posts on Stack Overflow alone, but I'm rate limiting it as not to flood the frontpage too much. Since you've been around for so long, you're bound to receive more edit notifications the coming year. It repairs posts oldest first and doesn't pay attention to who the author is.

Comment: @Glorfindel Great! Thank you so much for this. Any edit of yours will be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I got it: I used Window -> New Window and in the new window everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

pretty late for an answer but for people who bump into this problem in future :

This is probably a bug with eclipse. At least to me it seems so.

The hack: Close eclipse. Delete the metadata file from the workspace folder. Restart the eclipse in same workspace. Load all the existing projects one by one from the "Create project from existing source option"

Note: This is a non-elegant, but simple and fast hack for the lazy ones like me. I tried a few of them from above. None of them worked. This one works just fine. Yeah one thing - you will have to reset the Installed JREs to point to the JDK on your machine.

Comment: Thanks @Guy Sensei but if you read to the end of the comments on the best answer you'll see how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

there's also a notion of workspaces in eclipse which can sometimes be confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate the option "Focus on Active Task". (If you have installed the Mylyn plugin)

Answer (score 0):

'Top Level Elements/Working sets' - is not working
'Window -> New Window and in the new window everything is back to normal.' - it was ok for me at old version of Eclipse 2 weeks ago I have installed new one, and here it don't works

Comment: what new one have you installed?

Answer (score -1):

The most easy way you can follow is switch to another workspace from eclipse (go to file menu

// then switch workspace)and then import the projects(file menu // import // Existing Projects into Workspace) .